# How do I recruit beta testers?

Tags: ios, beta

We're a small company without enough employees to run a large scale beta in house.  The app is geo-location based so we're trying to recruits some beta testers from all over that aren't "friends and family".  Are there any sites or communities dedicated to something like this?

Comment: There isn't anything here specific to game development.  However you might have better luck on gamedev.net or reddit or something more general like that.

Comment: With that adjustment it is now a valid question. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: It's still not really game related - I'd suggest http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or plain SO.

Comment: Contact the computer science teachers at local schools (high schools, universities, etc.) and ask them if they would like to run some sort of a class project where the students write an analysis of the game (and note any bugs) in exchange for your company donating some funds to the school.  Some teachers may also see this as an opportunity to teach the students about the more serious side of gaming (since most teenagers seem to assume that a "game testing career" is all "fun and games" without the paperwork aspect), and because you'd be donating you could get copies of those students' reports.

Comment: Please note when answering, this shouldn't be a "list of" question. Answers should contain strategies for getting beta testers, not specific websites or places.

Comment: Using TestFlight and then tweeting something like #testflighttesters used to work, but that was a couple years ago so I don't know if that still works. I mean, I'd still recommend using TestFlight for distributing builds to your testers and managing the process, but I don't know if it still helps at all for recruiting testers in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find beta testers via my friend network, colleague or working network like Game Developer group on Facebook or LinkedIn or Twitter and on. But the options should not stop there. You can get ones by using game engine's forums to spread the words about your campaign (if you use 3rd party framework). Anyway, at least, you can start recruiting one by one starting from your interested friend then grow it a little by little and see it from there.